# How to Show-Hide twitter bootstrap popover with javascript global variable?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm having big trouble implementing Bootstrap's version of `popover()`. Actually I previously implemented my own version of popover and now I want to replace with Bootstrap. So my logics are implemented just need to change UI representation. So please give some solution for this.

My prevoius popup was the following, which was working fine:

```
this.myPopObj = new myPopupClass({
    title: 'Title',
    content: templateContent,
});
this.myPopObj.show();
```

After replacing my own implementation with Bootstrap's `popover()` my code becomes:

```
this.myPopObj = function(){
    $("#popupId").popover({
        title: 'Title',
        content: templateContent,
    });
}
this.myPopObj.show(); // doesn't work
```

Comment: some html will be nice but since you are using jquery have you tried .hide()?

Comment: yes I am using jquery... it throws an error in console
    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'close'

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)

```
$('#element').popover('show')
```

Answer (score 0):

I bind click event to the button and setTimeout with the class popover

and it works fun.

```
$('#click_button').popover({
  container: 'body',
  placement: 'top',
  trigger: 'focus',
  title: 'title',
  content: 'content'
});

$('#click_button').click(function(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.popover').fadeOut('slow',function() {});
  },2000);
});
```